# Add ability to whitelist all email addresses for sending emails using AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

So I get this error when I try to send an email, using AWS SES, inside a AWS lambda function...

```
User `arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/lambdaRole' is not authorized to perform 
`ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:xxx:identity/john@yyy.io'
```

Now I can solve this by adding this line to the lambda policy:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "ses:SendEmail"
  Resource:
    - !Sub "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:xxx:identity/john@yyy.io"
```

But I want to be able to send emails to any email address, and I dont want to have to add this line to the policy everytime I need to send a email to new email address.

Is there any way I can add something to the policy that allows me to send emails to all email addresses?

Here is my Kotlin code that uses the Java SES SDK...

```
val request = SendEmailRequest()
            .withDestination(Destination().withToAddresses("john@yyy.io"))
            .withMessage(Message()
                    .withBody(Body()
                            .withHtml(Content()
                                    .withCharset("UTF-8").withData(emailBody)))
                    .withSubject(Content()
                            .withCharset("UTF-8").withData("...")))
            .withSource("jim@ggg.io)


    SES_CLIENT.sendEmail(request)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That appears to be the sender address, not the recipient.

Comment: That can't be the case. I have attached my code to the question so you can see that the email address in the error message is the email that the email is being sent to...

Comment: Are you still [sandboxed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)?

Comment: Yep! Ah that must be it, maybe once I am out of the sandbox I won't need to add a ses:SendEmail action for every email address?

Comment: I suspect that to be the case.